# Can't extract frames from corrupted video files using python, but can play the videos on VLC

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture

I use python to extract frames from video files.
Specific now I use Open-CV.

I know that the files is some how corrupted I knew that there is a chance that I could not extract the frames as I want to, But because I can play them on VLC - I think it means that I still have a chance to extract the frames.

I tried also to use:

- moviepy
- imageio
- ffmepg directly using commands

It is also important to say that converting the file is not an option for me cause I don't want to install the video to my system.

I expect to be able to extract frames from some-how corrupted video files that can played on VLC, using python and without saving the files on my system.

## **Can anyone think of other way to extract those frames?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You may get some mileage by using `vlc` with python see: https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! 
I tried and it is not working for me also :(